# Salesforce integration with Codeless Platform

Tags: community, integration, salesforcedx, continuous-integration

Their is a requirement, that I want to build a connection between salesforce and SAP B1 system. Therefore, We used codeless platform as our middleware. I'm not clear about the connection details from salesforce side. They gave a support document in the below link,

https://www.codelessplatforms.com/knowledge-base/installing-configuring-salesforce-event-agent/#Configuration_Required_for_Salesforce

But I couldn't find clear endpoint url or WSDL file to make a request. If not how are we going to build a API request/ WEB service using above details? Could you please share your experience, If someone built a connection with the codeless platform from another platform.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something the link you shared did not require any 'URL or WSDL from salesforce side' - all information seems to be related to the configuration on the external platform.

Non-salesforce questions are of course best answered elsewhere, or by the specific product support teams.